# Prompt the user to enter a password on hyperlink

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, hyperlink, textbox

I want to prompt the user to enter a password when user clicks on the hyperlink to validate it with a pre-hard coded password to grant or deny access to the next page.

I am not sure where to put it either on code behind or client side. But when user clicks, it should open a text box.

For example:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style13"  ForeColor="Blue" NavigateUrl="http://someServer/SomePage.aspx">Some Page</asp:HyperLink> --> Open a textbox or something.
```

Code Behind:

```
if (textbox.text == 'Admin Password')
{
    navigate.url ('Go to page.aspx');
}
```

Is this possible, how it could be done?

Please note that the password will be pre-hard coded and it won't be held in a database for my usage right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily with the anchor tag on client side using a small code of JavaScript.

Although it is not a good approach to use a hard codded password inside the page either on server side(code behind) or especially on client side. But for the requirement you have right now, you can use the following snippet to achieve it.

---

Given below is the snippet that will do the work for you. On anchor tag click event you prompts the user to enter a password to proceed and checks it if it is `Admin Password` or not.

```js
function ValidatePassword() {

  var password = prompt("Please enter password to proceed", "");

  if (password == "Admin Password") {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://someServer/SomePage.aspx" id="HyperLink1" onclick="return ValidatePassword();">Some Page</a>
```